# std::vector::erase() doesn't want to move

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I've got a `std::vector<Foo>` where `Foo` is a class containing `Foo( Foo&& ) noexcept`.

Adding objects to the container works flawlessly, however erasing them using `std::vector::erase( iterator )` does not, GCC 4.7 tries to call the assignment operator which I have deleted. The exact error message is:

*error: use of deleted function ‘Foobar& Foobar::operator=(const Foobar&)*

**Edit:** Of course `std::vector` calls the assignment operator, not the copy constructor (you can see that in the error message, too). Fixed it in the description, sorry.

Here's example source code as requested:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() {}
        Foo( Foo&& other ) noexcept {}

        Foo( const Foo& ) = delete;
        Foo& operator=( const Foo& ) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> v;

    v.push_back( Foo{} );
    v.erase( v.begin() );
}
```

Comment: Without code, it's hard to see what the problem is

Comment: So your class is named `Foo` but you're getting an error message about `Foobar`? Something doesn't match. Real code, please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you did not provide a move assignment operator. This is part of the vector Movable requirements for some functions.

Comment: Oh. Hehe. I just typed up my own sample, and automatically added the move assignment operator. Explains why it worked for me then :) +1

Comment: The compiler error gives it all away- no suitable `operator=`.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce it. Turns out good habits go a long way: I had the move asignment operator defined.

Live on GCC 4.7.2: http://liveworkspace.org/code/36c600c285f2c91649fd4f73784c2c00

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}

    Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) throw() { }

    Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) throw() { return *this; }
};

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    std::vector<Foo> v;
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();

    auto it = v.begin();
    it++;
    v.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Actually a very good idea, however `erase()` doesn't like the move iterator, it says there's no matching function call for `std::move_iterator<...>`.

Comment: I just noticed, and updated the code. It turns out that in 'inventing' the replicating sample I automatically defined the move assignment operator, as @DeadMG suggests. Habits...

Comment: Hehe, interesting. Thanks a lot, providing the move assignment operator too makes perfect sense.

Comment: Any particular reason for using `throw()` over `noexcept`, or are they synonymous?

Comment: @ildjarn My local gcc version didn't yet accept the keyword. I'd _guess_ they would roughly mean the same, though `throw()` has many troubles so I'd prefer `noexcept`

Answer (score 1):

DeadMG's answer is excellent, however I'd like to promote another way of writing the assignment operator:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}

    Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) throw() { }

    Foo& operator=(Foo) throw() { return *this; }
};
```

Since you require a fresh temporary at the start of the method, the compiler will pick either the copy or move constructor to create this temporary on its own, and you do not have to write both a copy assignment operator AND a move assignment operator :)

Comment: He doesn't anyway, because his class is uncopyable.

Comment: @DeadMG: I'll avoid entering in the details of what is automatically defaulted and what is automatically deleted... it's too quirky.